# How to search in beginning of line and add something at end of that line

Tags: search, replace

I want to search lines beginning with certain string in Vim, and then add something at the end of file. I have tried the following but it removed everything instead of appending

```
:%s/^12138/*something_at_end_of_file/g
```

This search all lines which begin with `12138` but it removes everything and add `something_at_end_of_file`

But I want to preserve actually string and add at end of line.

Comment: Do you want to add something of the **lines** matching `^12138` or at the end of the **file**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the `:g` command:

```
:g/^12138/s/something-at-the-end$/something-new-at-the-end/
```

More information on `:help :g`

Comment: As an extra, `:g` has a sibling command: `:v`, which allows to run a command on every lines **not matching** a pattern.

Answer (score 3):

You may try this:

```
%s/\v^(12138.*)/\1something_at_end_of_line/g
```

That means:

`%s` substitute on all lines

`/\v`  starts search pattern and uses very-magic mode, saves you from the need to escape everything (see `:help \v`)

`^(12138.*)` starting from the beginning of the line, find all text that starts with `12138` and is followed by anything else (`.*`) and put it into a *group*

`/\1something_at_end_of_line/g` replace the found patterns with the first *group* content and then add your text.

HTH

Comment: Good answer, but you don’t need the group (or the `g` flag). You can use either `\0` or `&` to include the whole match in the replacement: `:%s/12138.*/\0something_at_end_of_line`

Answer (score 2):

Another similar alternative: use `:normal` and `A`ppend in a `:global` command:

```
:g/^12138/norm!Asomething_at_the_end
```